# Creating a service with repetitive method

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to create a service which does something every 5 seconds.
The problem is the moment I put the `while(true)` it gives me an error.
I imagine this is just not allowed. If so, what is a better way to implement a repetitive method?

```
public class repService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    while(true){
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    // do something
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
which every 5 seconds does something
```

You can use `Timer().schedule` to repeat task every 5 seconds.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do your task here

            }
        }, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000);
```

If you need to modify or play on UI part then make sure to write than code in `runOnUiThread`

Comment: if i want to start an AsyncTask which will pop a dialog on main UI (which i imagine refers to whichever activity the user is currently on). is AsyncTask a runnable action?

Comment: @vipulshah: does the timer run on a UI thread or a separate thread? Also, what if we use an alarm manager(but in this case would it consume more battery?)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put statements outside of a method to run. Put the **while loop** inside `onCreate` or `onStartCommand` methods of your service. These methods are guaranteed to called once your service is launched.

And for implementing a repetitive task, use `HandlerThread`, `Looper`, `Handler` and handler's `postDelayed` method to make good use of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something     
    }
}, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: will this loop every 5 seconds?

Comment: whats the diff from looper suggested by waqas

Comment: Yes it will, the difference is that he set the first parameter to be the date when to run it first time, while mine runs at once, the first parameter is the delay, and the second is the same as his, the interval.